# Mutate array with carried function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects I want to update with a new value that is dependent on the sequence.

So this:

```
[
  { "init": 3, "data": "..." },
  { "init": 3, "data": "..." },
  { "init": 3, "data": "..." },
  { "init": 5, "data": "..." },
  { "init": 6, "data": "..." },
  { "init": 6, "data": "..." },
  { "init": 7, "data": "..." },
  { "init": 8, "data": "..." }
  }
]
```

.. becomes this:

```
[
  { "init": 3, "group": "odd",  "data": "..." },
  { "init": 3, "group": "odd",  "data": "..." },
  { "init": 3, "group": "odd",  "data": "..." },
  { "init": 5, "group": "even", "data": "..." },
  { "init": 6, "group": "odd",  "data": "..." },
  { "init": 6, "group": "odd",  "data": "..." },
  { "init": 6, "group": "odd",  "data": "..." },
  { "init": 7, "group": "even", "data": "..." },
  { "init": 8, "group": "odd",  "data": "..." }
  }
]
```

That is, into each item insert a "group" element that according to whether it is in an even-most or odd-most group of "init" values.

The array is always sorted ascending by the "init" value".

NB. `"odd"` or `"even"` is *not* determined from the oddness/evenness of the `"init"` value, but the oddness/evenness of the *group* that init value falls into. In this example the *first* group of init values is "3", and so all items with `"init":"3"` is marked `"odd"`. The second group would be an "even" group, and thus marked *"even"*.

Comment: Is there a way to refer to the previous array member in the function for array.foreach? That is, if array.foreach is currently processing the item _n_, can the function refer to item _n-1_?

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach` provides you an index of the current element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not used very often, but the functions like `map` and `forEach` take an optional final argumnet to be used as `this` in the callback. You can take advantage of this to maintain state while proceeding through the loop.

For example:

```js
let a = [
    { "init": 3 },
    { "init": 3 },
    { "init": 3 },
    { "init": 5 },
    { "init": 6 },
    { "init": 6 },
    { "init": 7 },
    { "init": 8 }
  ]

let res = a.map(function({init}) {
    if (this.last !== init) this.even = !this.even
    this.last = init
    return {init, group:this.even ? "even": "odd" }
}, {last: undefined, even:true} )

console.log(res)
```

*One note of caution: because it's depending on `this`, you can't use an arrow function for the callback.*

Comment: `return {init, group:this.even}` .. does this imply that other elements of the array objects are not going to be preserved?

Comment: @Erics you can return anything. Whatever you return will be added to the array. I removed the extra properties because they weren’t related to the problem.

Comment: Good call on that `state` management. Did not think about that at all. Got my upvote.

Comment: @MarkMeyer the problem is to get an _updated_ array, so those extra properties are related. Using the _state_ parameter is perfect though, so updated your answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a `for` loop:

```
  let prev, odd =  false;
   for(const el of data) {
     if(prev !== el.init) odd = !odd;
     el.group = odd ? "odd" : "even";
     prev = el.init;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to determine group index and then [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create the output:

```js
let array = [
  { "init": 3, "data": "..." },
  { "init": 3, "data": "..." },
  { "init": 3, "data": "..." },
  { "init": 5, "data": "..." },
  { "init": 6, "data": "..." },
  { "init": 6, "data": "..." },
  { "init": 6, "data": "..." },
  { "init": 7, "data": "..." },
  { "init": 8, "data": "..." }
]

let groups = Array.from(new Set(array.map(x => x.init)));

let oddOrEven = index => (index % 2 !== 0 ? "even": "odd" );

let result = array.map(({init, ...rest}) => ({
    init: init,
    ...rest,
    group: oddOrEven(groups.findIndex(x => x === init))
}))

console.log(result)
```